# CKAN2.9.5 Error: SOLR schema version not supported: 1.6. Supported versions are [2.8, 2.9, 2.10]

Tags: solr, ckan

I'm experiencing the following error while trying to install ***CKAN 2.9.5*** from source on *Centos9Stream* (*Python3.8.13* environment).
*Solr 8.11.1* and *PostgreSQL 14* have installed without issues.

I'm following instructions from https://readthedocs.org/projects/ckan/downloads/pdf/latest/
When I run `ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini db init`, I get the error below:

`File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/__init__.py", line 391, in check_solr_schema_version raise SearchError('SOLR schema version not supported: %s. Supported' ckan.lib.search.common.SearchError: SOLR schema version not supported: 1.6. Supported versions are [2.8, 2.9, 2.10] (default) [ckan@localhost ~]$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema for SOLR 8.x+ is changed to use the following syntax

```
<schema name="ckan-2.10" version="1.6">
```

You can notice that the CKAN version now is set as `name` attribute

Comment: Hello tino097, I'm facing the same problem and, inf fact, my schema is set as you sad (`<schema name="ckan-2.10" version="1.6">`). Unfortunately, I didn't understand what I should do, or what changes I must make to resolve the problem. Could you help me?